# Insert a key value pair in each object if it is not present using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to add a particluar keyword in each line of a JSON file if it is not present already.

**My iniital file:**

```
[{"type": "STRING", "name": "Article"},
{"type": "STRING", "name": "Sellable_UOM"},
{"type": "STRING", "name": "PriceFamilyCode"},
{"type": "STRING", "name": "PriceFamilyDescription"},
{"type": "STRING", "name": "SalesDistrict"},
{"type": "DATE", "name": "FiscalWeekendDate"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "REPEATED", "name": "export_sql"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "REPEATED", "name": "post_sql"}]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[{"type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "Article"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "Sellable_UOM"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "PriceFamilyCode"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "PriceFamilyDescription"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "SalesDistrict"},
{"type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "FiscalWeekendDate"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "REPEATED", "name": "export_sql"},
{"type": "STRING", "mode": "REPEATED", "name": "post_sql"}]
```

**Requirement:**
If in case the line dosent contain the **mode** value then insert it as "mode": "NULLABLE" inbetween the type and name attributes.

My end result what i am trying to achive is to get the field and its corresponding datetype and mode as below, from the above expected output.

**FInal result:**

```
    Article,STRING,NULLABLE 
    Sellable_UOM,STRING,NULLABLE
    PriceFamilyCode,STRING,NULLABLE
    PriceFamilyDescription,STRING,NULLABLE
    SalesDistrict,STRING,NULLABLE
    FiscalWeekendDate,DATE,NULLABLE
    export_sql,STRING,REPEATED
    post_sql,STRING,REPEATED
```

The command i tried to achive this is from the expected output json is,

```
jq -r '.[] |[ .name, .type, .mode]|@csv'  file1.json | sed s/'"'//g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below program produces the expected output by inserting `mode: "NULLABLE"` pair between `type` and `name` keys of each object that doesn't have a `mode` key.

```
map(select(has("mode") | not) |= {type, mode: "NULLABLE", name})
```

But, if the aim here is to convert the input JSON to CSV, I don't think an intermediate structure is necessary. Assuming `mode` is either non-existent or a non-null value, the alternate operator can be used for a direct conversion as shown below.

```
.[] | [.type, .mode // "NULLABLE", .name] | @csv
```